# How to get the file system format of an SD Card in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, filesystems

I am new in Qt. I am working on an app where I need to display the file format(e.g. FAT32, NTFS) of the SD card that is connected to my PC.

Is their a Qt API that can help me achieve the result???

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. For that you have to ask the OS.

Comment: I looked through QFSFileEngine and QAbstractFileEngine but didnt find anything related to File format.

Comment: @Gojira: that is why i ansered the way i answered.